# how to move uinity launcher to the bottom ,help with step by step procedure?

Tags: launcher

Its so difficult to work with the unity launcher at the left of the screen, any procedure to move it to the bottom since in windows 7 its in bottom and another thing is it gives more space in the screen while working.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, there is no official way to do this and the tweak someone made for this was dangerous and hasn't been updated since 12.04. If you want, though, you could install the Kubuntu Desktop Environment, which is very much like Windows and has much more customizability, like multiple panels(launchers). Get it by running (in a terminal) `sudo apt-get install kubuntu-desktop`. Once it installs, log out, click the round icon to the right above the password field and select KDE.

Comment: Whats mean by KDE ?? will it install another version of ubuntu??

Comment: @Akashgt KDE is an alternate desktop environment for Ubuntu. It comes pre-installed on the Kubuntu distro, but can be added to any compatible version of Ubuntu.

Comment: You are a Linux noob aren't you?

Comment: Me? Why would you think that? @It'sWillem

Comment: @Akashgt And I quote: "in windows 7 its" "Whats mean by KDE ?? will it install another version of ubuntu?" "difficult"

Comment: Installed kubuntu its not so appealing.Moreover it changed my visuals in my ubuntu desktop also.How can i remove it?

Comment: It shouldn't have interfered with Unity. You just need to switch back to the Ubuntu option at the login screen.

Comment: @Zacharee1 After installing kubuntu it really messed up my previous appearance of my system.How can i remove it completely without affecting my original ubuntu??

Comment: What did it mess up? My Unity looks completely normal. Are icon colors and such different?

Comment: This answer might need to be updated since, as of 16.04 LTS it is possible to move launcher to the bottom . In fact , this question may be closed as duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/q/760457/295286