# which version of Ubuntu I am running?

Tags: upgrade, 16.04

This is one of old Desktop(2010) - Dual Core AMD Processor, 12 GB of RAM, 640 GB for Linux. It has USB drives but one cannot boot from USB. Somehow using the n/w installer I had installed 14.04 LTS few months back.
Now i tried to upgrade it to 16.04 LTS...got into some issues - it let me first upgrade to 15.10 and then from there to 16.04 LTS. Everything was done on the command line(shell) as my software updater was not working as expected.

Finally after lots of efforts with broken installation - I am confused which version of Ubuntu Linux I am running. 
lsb_release - a says 16.04 while unity desktop says 15.10.
[image]
[image]

[image]

What could be the problem? How i can verify that 16.04 LTS is successfully installed or not?

And my doubt is getting stronger now...i tried to do software-update...it says due to last upgrade...i should partial update..when i tried that...getting this error...it's thinking that i am trying to upgrade from 16.04 to 15.10 which is not supported.

As my upgrade from 14.04 to 16.04(in between forced 15.10 upgrade) didn't happened in the way it was suppose to happen...i am getting all these issues.
[image]

Moreover as per this [link](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/XenialXerus/ReleaseNotes)-Ubuntu 16.04 LTS comes with kernel 4.4
When i test it on my Ubuntu:

```
ashu@ashu-old-pc:~$ uname -a
Linux ashu-old-pc 4.2.0-36-generic #41-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 18 15:49:10 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: You're using 16.04 .  The "desktop" that you're talking about is just a background image with "15.10" written on it, isn't it?  What happens if you change your background image to something else?  Presumably, everything, including the "15.10" will go away?

Answer (score 0):

Easy test: If you can change launcher position to bottom you are running 16.04

Also, don't trust wallpapers ;)

Comment: that's not happening

Comment: @Ashu Followed all the right methods as show in http://askubuntu.com/q/760457/295286  ?

Comment: 'root@ashu-old-pc:/home/ashu# gsettings set com.canonical.Unity.Launcher launcher-position Bottom
No such key 'launcher-position' Getting error...

Answer (score 0):

One way to ensure you're running 16.04 would be to just reinstall ubuntu 16.04, that way you know its deffo the right version.

I had a problem where I had to reinstall ubuntu, but I didn't want to loose my files I had and I didn't have any device for backing it up, so what I did was reinstall 16.04 via usb (The one usb I had was in use*). On the installation menu I just clicked "Something else" and installed Ubuntu into the same partition as the one I previously used. It'll ask if you wish to retain the /home directory that it finds there.

That worked for me man. So you can reinstall ubuntu 16.04 without loosing your files, which is just awesome.