# What versions of Unity are these?

Tags: unity, 64-bit, gui, 32-bit

At home I run Ubuntu 16.04 x64.
At the office I installed Ubuntu 16.04 x86 due to available hardware.
The 64-bit and 32-bit versions of Unity are not the same. Can it be that the 32-bit version is an early version of Unity?

[image: Unity_32bit.jpg]

[image: Unity_64bit.jpg]

Comment: The 32 one is not Unity. KDE.

Comment: That's Unity with the launcher at the bottom. It's a new feature in 16.04. See here: http://askubuntu.com/q/760457/301745

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Rinzwind said in the comments, the 32-bit one is **not** Unity. It is either KDE or XFCE.

- [Ubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ubuntu_(operating_system)) uses Unity.
- [Kubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubuntu) uses KDE.
- [Xubuntu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xubuntu) uses XFCE.

For your convience, here's the 32-bit version of 16.04.1LTS with Unity: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.1-desktop-i386.iso